# Removing identical values on the same lines of a csv file using python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a.csv file that was sent to me but there is more than one of the same value in the lines

**Approach**
I want to remove values that already exist on the same line and keep only one

**Technical specification :**
Windows 10
Python 3.6
CSV file with 6000000 lines

**Sample of the csv file :**

```
323|2013-06-03 00:00:00|(B)|(B)|(B)|(B)|100||Dort
323|2013-06-03 01:00:00|||||99||
323|2013-06-03 02:00:00|||||100||Dort
323|2013-06-03 03:00:00|||||97||
323|2013-06-03 04:00:00|||(B)|(B)|97||Dort
323|2013-06-03 05:00:00|||||97||
323|2013-06-03 06:00:00|||||97||
323|2013-06-03 07:00:00|||(B)|(B)|96||Dort
323|2013-06-03 08:00:00|(D)|(D)|(B)|(B)|100||Éveillé-réceptif
```

**Desired result**

```
323|2013-06-03 00:00:00|(B)|100||Dort
323|2013-06-03 01:00:00|||||99||
323|2013-06-03 02:00:00|||||100||Dort
323|2013-06-03 03:00:00|||||97||
323|2013-06-03 04:00:00|||(B)|97||Dort
323|2013-06-03 05:00:00|||||97||
323|2013-06-03 06:00:00|||||97||
323|2013-06-03 07:00:00|||(B)|96||Dort
323|2013-06-03 08:00:00|(D)|(B)|100||Éveillé-réceptif
```

Comment: You can for each line make a list of it, then use `set` to remove duplicates. However, that might change the order of the items.

Comment: use csv module, then look up "how to remove duplicates from a list whilst preserving order"

Comment: Yes the different values can pop up anywhere and there can be as many numbers, letters or other characters as possible after the datetime 
The sample is copy and paste of the real csv

Comment: Indeed, a bit too eager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv

with open('data.csv') as f_in, open('data_out.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_out:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f_in, delimiter='|')
    csvwriter = csv.writer(f_out, delimiter='|')

    for row in csvreader:
        r = []
        while row:
            v, row = row[0], row[1:]
            if v in row and len(v) > 0:
                continue
            r.append(v)
        csvwriter.writerow(r)
```

Data in output file:

```
323|2013-06-03 00:00:00|(B)|100||Dort
323|2013-06-03 01:00:00|||||99||
323|2013-06-03 02:00:00|||||100||Dort
323|2013-06-03 03:00:00|||||97||
323|2013-06-03 04:00:00|||(B)|97||Dort
323|2013-06-03 05:00:00|||||97||
323|2013-06-03 06:00:00|||||97||
323|2013-06-03 07:00:00|||(B)|96||Dort
323|2013-06-03 08:00:00|(D)|(B)|100||Éveillé-réceptif
```

Comment: thank you, it worked perfectly but a space line is added between each line in the output file

Comment: @Zenix hmm, on my system the output file is normal. try `open('data_out.csv', 'w', newline='')` when opening the file for writing.

Comment: @Andrey Kesely it corrected the minor problem, Thanks for your help